# Error with/using ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

We are creating an `ArrayList` from a File, which contains both integers (odometer reading) and doubles (gallons per fill up). We're using them to make a mileage. We are then using a container class to access them, so on and so fourth.

The container looks like this:

```
package lab08;

public class FillUp{
   private final int odometer;
   private final double gallons;


  public FillUp(int givenOdometer, double givenGallons){
  odometer = givenOdometer;
  gallons = givenGallons;
  }

public int getOdometer(){
return odometer;
}

 public double getGallons(){
 return gallons;
 }
```

}

My code looks like the following:

```
public class MileageCalculator {    

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException{
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("/Users/Mobile_Hive/Desktop/Homework/mileage.txt"));
            double mileage=0.0;
            int i=0;
            System.out.println(fillUpArray(scan).get(0));
            /**
            while(i+1<fillUpArray(scan).size()){
                mileage=(((FillUp)fillUpArray(scan).get(i+1)).getOdometer()-((FillUp) fillUpArray(scan).get(i)).getOdometer())/((FillUp) fillUpArray(scan).get(i+1)).getGallons();
                System.out.println("Mileage: "+mileage);
                i++;
            }
           **/ 
        }
    private static ArrayList<FillUp> fillUpArray(Scanner scan){
        ArrayList<FillUp> list = new ArrayList<FillUp>();
        int odometer=0;
        double gallons=0.0;
        while(scan.hasNextLine()){
        String line = scan.nextLine();
        Scanner scans = new Scanner(line);
        while(scans.hasNext()){
            odometer=scans.nextInt();
            gallons=scans.nextDouble();
        }
        FillUp fill = new FillUp(odometer, gallons);
        list.add(fill);
        }
        return list;
    }
```

I am using the comments to occlude off my method for getting the actual mileage calculation and attempting to see if I can even access indexes of the ArrayList I have attempted to make....
When I run this in its current form I get:

```
lab08.FillUp@3bbf502d
```

When I remove the comments around "while(i+1< ) etc" leading to "i++" I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 0
at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:635)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:411)
at lab08.MileageCalculator.main(MileageCalculator.java:15)
```

I feel like in the first situation, I am not accessing the index of the array list, almost like it has not been filled. In the second attempt, I am not quite sure what is happening.
I am not looking for straight forward answers, but maybe just explanation as to what is happening with very stripped down instructions on what needs to happen. I also would love information on what is happening so if someone can push me to some reading material that would be awesome.

Comment: Override toString in your FillUp class.

Comment: Yes, you're printing out the first element of the list, which is a `FillUp`. But you haven't overridden `toString()` in the `FillUp` class, which is why you're getting output like that... For your loop, obtain an `ArrayList` *once* instead of calling `fillUpArray` in your loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time you call `fillUpArray(scan)` you are getting a different `ArrayList`, whose size may be completely different than what you got in the previous call to that method. You should call that method once and store its output in a variable, so that you use the same list.

```
        List list = fillUpArray(scan);
        System.out.println(list.get(0));
        while(i+1<list.size()){
            mileage=(((FillUp)list.get(i+1)).getOdometer()-((FillUp) list.get(i)).getOdometer())/((FillUp) list.get(i+1)).getGallons();
            System.out.println("Mileage: "+mileage);
            i++;
        }
```

Comment: gave this a try, getting this error.... Once again, I feel like List is not filling or populating correctly....


Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0

 at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:635)
 at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:411)
 at lab08.MileageCalculator.main(MileageCalculator.java:17)

Also, with the SOP it prints out the same as before,

    lab08.FillUp@1647ad40
Which I feel like I need to add a toString....

Comment: @Loomiss There was another call to fillUpArray inside the loop which I forgot to replace. If you didn't replace it either, it might explain the error. See my edit.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works now. I know what is happening (like all the commands and such) I just couldn't figure out the specifics behind the error which was frustrating to me. I am also on a limited time line (Recert'ing my medical army license all week...)  can you point me to a good/in-depth article/source of for reading up on ArrayList/Arrays in general to make sure I have a good base knowledge on this stuff?